# Is there a safe way to create a subprocess from a thread in python?

Tags: python, multithreading

I'm working with some existing code that creates a number of different worker threads who then in turn call some shell scripts with subprocess/multiprocessing. From what I've seen, that's a no-no since mutexes can get wedged in the child process' interpreter before the exec() happens. Is that a valid concern? If so, is there some sort of python primitive that "does the right thing" and executes a fork/exec without playing with anything unsafe in-between?

Thanks

Comment: I don't think so. You can definitely create deadlocks simply using the `logging` module(which is thread safe and thus does some locking) and `subprocess`/`multiprocessing`, so I'd say python does not handle this for you.

Comment: I'm surprised there isn't some sort of module/primitive implemented in C where it calls fork() and exec() immediately back to back (which won't deadlock)

Comment: `multiprocessing` does much more then simply spawning a subprocess, thus it's not possible to do what you think. This is a "design flaw" of `fork`. The simpler way to deal with it is to avoid forking processes that have multiple threads.

Comment: Did you ever come to a conclusion on this. I'm having the same issue (forking from a thread deadlocks, sometimes). The multiprocessing module is not a good option for me (sub-job params are large or not pickleable)