# python3: does multiprocessing.Lock() also lock at the thread level?

Tags: python-3.x, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading

I have recently switched from `threading` to `multiprocessing` in my python3 program. This seems to work fine, and the `multiprocessing.Lock()` call seems to indeed successfully work as it's supposed to within multiple threads of execution that I spawn from within my program.

However, my program itself is invoked from another, higher-order module which runs separate instances of my program via normal Python threads. I have no ability to rewrite the code of that module.

I previously was using `threading.Lock()` and `threading.RLock()` to manage shared code in this environment, and I'm wondering if `multiprocessing.Lock()` will do the same as `threading.Lock()` or `threading.RLock()` when it is invoked within separate threads of the same process.

Or will I have to implement some sort of hybrid locking mechanism to make sure my shared resources are all safe within my combination`multiprocessing`-and-`threading` environment?

If a hybrid is needed, would the following be sufficient? ...

```
with multiprocessing.Lock():
    with threading.Lock():  # threading.RLock() in some cases
        # code that I want to protect
```

... or would I have to implement something more sophisticated, perhaps via a new locking context manager that I would have to write?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally found the answer to my question:
[Safe to call multiprocessing from a thread in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46439740/safe-to-call-multiprocessing-from-a-thread-in-python)

I now see that calling `multiprocessing.Lock()` from within a threaded environment will not work. I had previously posted some code here that created a hybrid `multiprocessing/threading` lock object, but I have now deleted that code, because it is incorrect.