# Why the thread inherited by the child process is in the stopped status while in parent process is in the status started?

Tags: python, linux, multithreading, multiprocessing, fork

### Safely forking a multithreaded process is problematic

I'm learning to use the `multiprocessing` module. Now I'm focusing on the following sentence:

> Note that safely forking a multithreaded process is problematic.

present in the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#contexts-and-start-methods) in the section dedicated to **context an start methods**.

About this topic I have read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46439740/safe-to-call-multiprocessing-from-a-thread-in-python/46440564#46440564) which contains the statement:

> "Note that safely forking a multithreaded process is problematic": here **problematic** is quite an euphemism for "impossible".

### Test code

I have written this test code (for **Linux** platform):

```
import multiprocessing
import threading
import time

a = 1
t1 = None

def thread_function_1():
    global a
    while True:
        time.sleep(2)
        a += 1

def p1():
    global a
    global t1
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        print(f"Process p1 ---> a = {a}, t1 = {t1}, t1 is_alive = {t1.is_alive()}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    multiprocessing.set_start_method('fork')
    t1 = threading.Thread(target = thread_function_1)
    t1.start()
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=p1)
    p.start()
    while True:
        a += 1
        time.sleep(1)
        print(f"Thread Main ---> a = {a}, t1 = {t1}, t1 is_alive = {t1.is_alive()}")
```

I'm running the code on **Linux** so the instruction:

```
multiprocessing.set_start_method('fork')
```

selects a start method which is already *The default start method* on Linux. This is because for the test I'm using Python 3.6 (from documentation: **The default start method will change away from fork in Python 3.14.**).

The output of its execution is:

```
Thread Main ---> a = 2, t1 = <Thread(Thread-1, started 140618847368960)>, t1 is_alive = True
Process p1 ---> a = 1, t1 = <Thread(Thread-1, stopped 140618847368960)>, t1 is_alive = False
Thread Main ---> a = 4, t1 = <Thread(Thread-1, started 140618847368960)>, t1 is_alive = True
Process p1 ---> a = 1, t1 = <Thread(Thread-1, stopped 140618847368960)>, t1 is_alive = False
Thread Main ---> a = 5, t1 = <Thread(Thread-1, started 140618847368960)>, t1 is_alive = True
Process p1 ---> a = 1, t1 = <Thread(Thread-1, stopped 140618847368960)>, t1 is_alive = False
Thread Main ---> a = 7, t1 = <Thread(Thread-1, started 140618847368960)>, t1 is_alive = True
Process p1 ---> a = 1, t1 = <Thread(Thread-1, stopped 140618847368960)>, t1 is_alive = False
```

The output shows that:

- the process `p1` has a reference to the global variable `t1` which points to an instance of the class `Thread`; but in Main process the thread is in the status *started*, when in the process `p1` is in the status  *stopped*
- see also the different value returned by the method `is_alive()` (*true* in Main, *false* in `p1`)
- previous considerations are confirmed by the fact that in the process `p1` the value of the variable `a` is always `1` while in the Main process is increased by the thread  `t1`.

### Question

Why the thread inherited by the child process is in the stopped status while in parent process is in the status started?
This behavior is linked to the sentence *"Note that safely forking a multithreaded process is problematic."*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why the thread inherited by the child process is in the stopped status while in parent process is in the status started?

I suppose it would be better to have some status that indicates that the thread never really existed at all. But the thread is stopped in the child because that thread never existed in the context of the child process.

If you're asking why the thread isn't running in the child, it's because that would lead to absolute chaos. Suppose that thread was in a library function that interacted with some service. Duplicating the thread could result in an invalid sequence of operations on that service.

> This behavior is linked to the sentence "Note that safely forking a multithreaded process is problematic."?

I suppose so. For example, suppose one of the other threads held a lock when you called `fork`. That lock will never be released in the child process because the thread that would unlock it doesn't exist.

Comment: Thank you David. Your sentence "Suppose that thread was in a library function that interacted with some service. Duplicating the thread could result in an invalid sequence of operations on that service." is exactly one of my doubts of using the module `multiprocessing`.