# bug in cross-process synchronisation using python's multiprocessing.Event from thread pool?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, distributed-computing

In a distributed system we're building at work we are using [redis's distributed locks](https://redis.io/docs/manual/patterns/distributed-locks/) to synchronise multiple accesses to the results of a calculation. (We're using the [py-redis implementation](https://redis-py.readthedocs.io/en/v5.0.1/lock.html))

Calculations can die for various reasons, and so we use a timeout on the lock so that if a worker dies the lock will eventually be released and waiting clients will be able to handle this case.

Since calculations can take a variable length time, there is no single timeout value which fits all, so we spawn a separate daemonised process which will regularly refresh the lock whilst the parent is alive.

- While the calculation is running we refresh the lock.
- When the calculation is done we stop the refresh process and unlock.
- If the worker dies it won't lave orphans behind, so the child refresh process will be killed and the lock will eventually timeout.

### Problem

We're using `multiprocessing.Event` to communicate between the parent process and the `multiprocessing.Process` `"refresh"` child process.

Originally the child process would loop on the `Event`, refreshing the lock until the event is set by the parent.

However, there are times where the `multiprocessing.Process.start` call doesn't seem to actually start the process, and so the la

There are situations where it seems as if `refresh.start()` fails to start the child process.

To be pedantic I then added a 2nd `Event` which the parent waits on, and the child sets when it starts.

We witness the parent waiting forever on this event.

### Example app

I have boiled the problem down to the following example app which exhibits the deadlock behaviour:

**The locking code which spawns the refresh process, yields to the caller, and then unlocks:**

```py
@contextlib.contextmanager
def lock(no):
    '''
    starts the refresh child, waits for it to start, yields to the caller, and 
    then upon return signals the child we are done and waits for it to exit
    '''
    start_ev = multiprocessing.Event()
    done_ev = multiprocessing.Event()

    # would obtain lock here and pass it to refresh
    # lock = redis.lock(...)

    refresh = multiprocessing.Process(target=wait_for_done, args=(start_ev, done_ev, no), daemon=True)
    refresh.start()

    while not start_ev.is_set():
        print(f"{no}: wait for start")
        start_ev.wait(1)

    print(f"{no}: ready to work")

    yield

    print(f"{no}: work complete")

    done_ev.set()
    refresh.join()
```

**This child process run function which refreshes the lock until the parent is done:**

```py
def wait_for_done(start_ev, done_ev, no):
    '''
    the refresh job - signals to the caller it has started, then loops on the done 
    event, refreshing the lock 
    '''
    print(f"{no}: start")
    start_ev.set()

    while not done_ev.is_set():
        # would refresh lock here
        # lock.reacquire()

        print(f"{no}: wait for done")
        done_ev.wait(1)

    print(f"{no}: done")
```

**The example calculation task and thread pool which shows we eventually deadlock:**

```py
def task(no):
    '''
    example calculation which needs to be locked
    '''
    with lock(no):
        print(f"{no}: working...")
        sleep = random.randint(3, 5)
        time.sleep(sleep)

# kick off multiple jobs to show some of them fail to synchronise
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(8) as pool:
    fs = []
    for i in range(8):
        f = pool.submit(task, i)
        fs.append(f)

    [ f.result() for f in fs ]
```

Running this will correctly start and stop some of the child processes, but eventually it will just get stuck.

### Output:

```
0: wait for start
0: start
3: wait for start
0: wait for done
3: start
2: wait for start
0: ready to work
0: working
...
4: wait for start
5: wait for start
4: wait for start
5: wait for start
4: wait for start
5: wait for start
4: wait for start
5: wait for start
...repeat forever
```

I guess that I'm using `multiprocessing` incorrectly but am not sure where I'm going wrong?

Perhaps it's got something to do with the fact I'm doing this concurrently from multiple python threads (the `concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor`), but given python doesn't have "real" threads because of the GIL, and it's interacting with `multiprocessing` which should be inherently thread safe, I would guess not?

Is what I'm trying to do here with `multiprocessing` workable?

How can I achieve my distributed locking with out-of-band refresh in the manner described above?

### Full source code below:

```py
import concurrent.futures
import random
import time
import multiprocessing
import contextlib


@contextlib.contextmanager
def lock(no):
    '''
    starts the refresh child, waits for it to start, yields to the caller, and 
    then upon return signals the child we are done and waits for it to exit
    '''
    start_ev = multiprocessing.Event()
    done_ev = multiprocessing.Event()

    # would obtain lock here and pass it to refresh
    # lock = redis.lock(...)

    refresh = multiprocessing.Process(target=wait_for_done, args=(start_ev, done_ev, no), daemon=True)
    refresh.start()

    while not start_ev.is_set():
        print(f"{no}: wait for start")
        start_ev.wait(1)

    print(f"{no}: ready to work")

    yield

    print(f"{no}: work complete")

    done_ev.set()
    refresh.join()


def wait_for_done(start_ev, done_ev, no):
    '''
    the refresh job - signals to the caller it has started, then loops on the done 
    event, refreshing the lock 
    '''
    print(f"{no}: start")
    start_ev.set()

    while not done_ev.is_set():
        # would refresh lock here
        # lock.reacquire()

        print(f"{no}: wait for done")
        done_ev.wait(1)

    print(f"{no}: done")


def task(no):
    '''
    example task which needs to be locked
    '''
    with lock(no):
        print(f"{no}: working...")
        sleep = random.randint(3, 5)
        time.sleep(sleep)

# kick off multiple jobs to show some of them fail to synchronise
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(8) as pool:
    fs = []
    for i in range(8):
        f = pool.submit(task, i)
        fs.append(f)

    [ f.result() for f in fs ]
```

Comment: Commenting on my own question: Seems there is an issue with using `fork` (which multiprocessing uses by default on linux) with multithreaded programs: Quote: [Note that safely forking a multithreaded process is problematic.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#contexts-and-start-methods). Spawning and forkserver present other problems, so thus far my high level problem still exists, hence not closing the question.

Comment: If you are executing `lock = redis.lock(...)` in function `lock`, then you are forking a process from a thread that holds a lock and you might wish to check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46439740/safe-to-call-multiprocessing-from-a-thread-in-python), which appears to be relevant.

Comment: @Booboo thank you, very illuminating. Definitely seems like we are heading down the wrong direction following this path

Comment: You probably know that you can use `multiprocessing.set_start_method('spawn')` to use the *spawn* rather than *fork* method of starting child processes. You will, of course, need to place any code at global scope that results in spawning new processes if a `if __name__ == '__main__':` block.

Comment: Yes, we tried that, thanks - but the redis lock causes an issue due to being unable to be pickled. We have since found an alternative solution which achieves the same end via a standalong watcher process and file locks